# How to generate hierarchical data in mockaroo?

Tags: data-generation

I want to generate some mock data in mockaroo.

The format of the data should be like this

```
Claim ID   Claim subid
1           1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            2
2            3
3            1
```

So, basically the claimdid column can have multiple subids. Is this possible?